# If statements not functioning in while loop (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm a C++ noob right now, pretty new to the language. I'm trying to write a program that calculates the time in other US time zones based on your current time. I have written a while loop in a void function, but the if statements used to keep the hours in range (1 - 12) fail to work. If you pick a time and a zone that does not get altered, such as 8:35 PM Eastern, it works just fine. However, if the hours go over 12 or under 0, the if statements do nothing. I've tried putting them outside the while loop. I've also tried to make a for loop. The solution is probably very simple to all of you, but any help would be very appreciated. Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// to be used when input is invalid (duh)
void invalid()
{

 for(int i; i < 40; i++) 
 {
   std::cout << "\n";
 }
 std::cout << "Invaild input.\n\n";
}

// switches am to pm to match the cycle (I had to put in the equal sign because 12 changes to cycle, but it still a valid hour, so I couldn't change the if statement's parameters)

void amstay(bool x, int y)
{
 if (x == true && y >= 12)
     {
       std::cout << " PM";
     }
 else if(x == false && y >= 12)
     {
       std::cout << " AM";
     }
}

void amswitch(bool x, int y)
{
 if (x == true && y >= 12)
     {
       std::cout << " PM";
     }
 else if(x == false && y >= 12)
     {
       std::cout << " AM";
     }
}

// used to display the zone's time
void finTimeDisplay(int h, int m, bool a, int x)
{
 int i;

 // Had to use an array because vectors weren't working for some reason :/
 std::string altZoneDisplay [4] = {"Pacific Time: ","\nMountain Time: ","\nCentral Time: ","\nEastern Time: "};
 //got to return to the while loop
 whileloop:
 // displays the vector and return the hours plus the index it is on (and the minute) when the hours are valid
 while(h <= 12 && h > 0 && i < 4)
 {
   std::cout << altZoneDisplay[i] << (h + i) + x<< ":" << m;
   i++;

   // returns hours to the beginning of it's cycle (1) 
   if (h > 12)
   {
     h = (h - 12) + x;
     std::cout << altZoneDisplay[i] << h + i << ":" << m;
     amswitch(a, h);
     goto whileloop;
   }
   // returns hours to the end of it's cycle
   else if (h < 0)
   {
     std::cout << altZoneDisplay[i] << h + 12 << ":" << m;
     amswitch(a, h);
     goto whileloop;
   }
 }
}


int main()
{


 // to add to hours (if you pick mountain, central, or eastern zones, you must have a lesser value for i or else it will register your time for pacific every time)


 int iAdd0 = 0;
 int iAdd1 = -1;
 int iAdd2 = -2;
 int iAdd3 = -3;

 int minutes;
 int hours;
 std::string amOrPm;
 bool am;
  int zone;

 std::vector<std::string> zoneDisplay (4);
 zoneDisplay.push_back ("\n1. Pacific");
 zoneDisplay.push_back ("\n2. Mountain");
 zoneDisplay.push_back ("\n3. Central");
 zoneDisplay.push_back ("\n4. Eastern");

 zonepick:

 std::cout << "\nUS Time Zone Converter\n\n================\n\nEnter a Timezone:";

 // for loop for display and goto for invalid input

 display:

 for(int i; i<zoneDisplay.size(); i++)
 {

   std::cout << zoneDisplay[i] << "\n";
 }
 std::cout << "\n";

 std::cin >> zone;
 if(zone != 1 && zone != 2 && zone != 3 && zone != 4) {
   invalid();
   goto display;
 }


 // goto for invalid input
 hourspick:
 std::cout << "\nEnter the time (hours): ";
 std::cin >> hours;
 if (hours > 12)
 {
   invalid();
   goto hourspick;
 }

 // goto for invalid input

 minutespick:
 std::cout << "\nEnter the time (minutes): ";
 std::cin >> minutes;
 if (minutes > 60)
 {
   invalid();
   goto minutespick;
 }

 // goto for invalid input

 ampmcycle:
 std::cout << "\nAM or PM? ";
 std::cin >> amOrPm;
 if (amOrPm == "am" || amOrPm == "AM")
 {
   am = true;
 }
 else if (amOrPm == "pm" || amOrPm == "PM")
 {
   am = false;
 }
 else {
   invalid();
   goto ampmcycle;
 }


 // didn't use booleans because that would waste space

 for (int i; i < 4; i++) {
   if (zone == i) {

   }
 }

 if (zone == 1)
 {
   finTimeDisplay(hours, minutes, am, iAdd0);
 }
 else if (zone == 2)
 {
   finTimeDisplay(hours, minutes, am, iAdd1);
 }
 else if (zone == 3)
 {
   finTimeDisplay(hours, minutes, am, iAdd2);
 }
 else if (zone == 4) {
   finTimeDisplay(hours, minutes, am, iAdd3);
 }


 /* 
 I thought this would work as a replacement for the if statements above. It didn't. 
 for (int i; i < 4; i++) 
 {
   if (zone == i) {
     finTimeDisplay(hours, minutes, am, iAdds.at(i));
   }
 }
*/
}
```

Comment: In which C++ book did you learn how to use such a disturbing number of `goto`s? Whichever book it is, you need to find a different C++ book. `goto`s in proper C++ are very, very rare.

Comment: `goto whileloop` should be `continue` or even just be omitted. `goto` is rarely necessary in modern c++

Comment: You must have gotten some compiler warnings about your uninitialized loop variables. Always pay attention to warnings and fix the errors. There are lots of errors in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The if statements do nothing because you never reach the if statements. Look at the code

```
 while(h <= 12 && h > 0 && i < 4)
 {
     ...
     if (h > 12)
     {
```

You only get into the loop if `h <= 12`, so `h > 12` **can never be true**. Same problem for `if (h < 0)`.